# Set onItemClick to pass ListView item data to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-listview, fragment

I set up a list view from JSON in a fragment and I am trying to, when an item is clicked, change view to a new fragment and also pass clicked item information to the new fragment to send to a PHP server for a response (to generate a new list view). I am new to fragments and haven't found a good explanation of how I can integrate this to my onItemClick() function.

channelList.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ConnectFragment extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
ArrayList <Channels> channelList;
ChannelListAdapter adapter;

public ConnectFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    channelList = new ArrayList<Channels>();
    getJSON("http://192.168.43.149/schoolTV/channelList.php");
    return rootView;
}

private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {
    String result;
//      InputStream is=null;
    final ProgressDialog[] dialog = new ProgressDialog[1];
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //dialog[0] = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            //dialog[0].setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            //dialog[0].setTitle("Connecting server");
            //dialog[0].show();
            //dialog[0].setCancelable(false);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                loadIntoListView(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
    getJSON.execute();
}

private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    //String[] channels = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        //channels[i] = obj.getString("name");

        Channels channel = new Channels();

        channel.setTitle(obj.getString("channelName"));
        channel.setDescription(obj.getString("channelDescriptipn"));
        //channel.setDateCreated(obj.get("createdOn"));
        channel.setImage(obj.getString("logoLocation"));

        channelList.add(channel);
    }
    //ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    ChannelListAdapter adapter = new ChannelListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.jsonparsedata_item, channelList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnClickListener();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {


        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to a new fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.frame_layout,new MainFragment()).commit();
```

frame_layout is the container view ID and MainFragment is the name of the fragment you wanna add.

...........................................

In your new fragment, create an object same as the item you wanna have the information of. In your onClick method refer to that object of your new fragment and put the information in it.

Comment: Hi @backslashN thanks. It Worked. Though unfortunately, while the content of the new fragment is viewed, I can still see the  previous fragments' contents.

Comment: In your layout, make the background of your fragment white. android:background="#fff"